# Excel function to show time based on timezone

Tags: excel, if-statement, time, timezone

I have created an excel sheet that If I enter an area code in Cell A, Cell B gives the timezone.

Now what I want to do is if **Cell B is equal to a value** (i.e. E, C, M or P), **Cell C shows the current time in that time zone**.

These are the supposed values:

E =NOW() *which is the current time*

C =current time -1

M =current time -2

P =current time -3

UTC-9 =current time -4

UTC-10 =current time -5

Comment: Keep in mind that with this approach, you will not actually know the precise time in some other part of the world, because daylight saving time rules there may be different than your own.  See also "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the most efficient way to do this, but I would create a small lookup table with the zone in one column and the time difference in the next coloumn. For example:

[image]

You can then add the following formula to cell C:

```
=NOW()-TIME(VLOOKUP(B1,$H$1:$I$6,2,FALSE),0,0)
```

B1 is cell B, and H1:I6 is the reference table that has been set up.